# Can you IFERROR Importxml

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm a beginner. I have the formula below which works to pull in the `payment date` from the table for stocks with a dividend (A9 is the stock ticker), but doesn't for stocks w/out a dividend (no table).
I get:

```
#value -"unable to parse query string from function query parameter 2: no column:Col6"
```

I would like it to return `0.00` when there is no dividend.  Thanks

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/",A9,"/dividend-history"),"//tbody//tr[1]"),"select Col6 LIMIT 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping in [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) should be adequate:

```
=iferror(QUERY(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/",A9,"/dividend-history"),"//tbody//tr[1]"),"select Col6 LIMIT 1"),"")
```

but if you must have `0.00` then:

```
=iferror(QUERY(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/",A9,"/dividend-history"),"//tbody//tr[1]"),"select Col6 LIMIT 1"),"0.00")
```

Returns Text (for the sake of the required format).